# how to find grids in table using splinter?

Tags: python, dom, web-scraping, splinter

I want to find elements in the table like this:
[image]

I tried

```py
b.find_by_id('resourceTd_5897')
```

and

```py
b.find_by_css('td#resourceTd_5897.resourceTd')
```

and even

```py
b.find_by_tag('td')
```

They all raise `no elements could be found with......` exception.

How can I find the grid in the table?

Comment: Are these elements dynamic i.e. do the ids change over time or are they static? And what happens if you select the table first with id of resourceTable?

Comment: Haven't used splinter before, but if the table is generated using JavaScript, the table will be loaded after the DOM is loaded and so you need a headless browser to first render the JavaScript before scraping it. Or the table might be loaded inside an iframe. If neither is the case, check if the `b` variable is set correctly.

Comment: I don't know if these elements are dynamic, how can I check. And I tried `b.find_by_id('resourceTable')` , still couldn't find.

Comment: @xinyueLiu can you provide us your target page url ?

Comment: http://172.16.213.7/gymbook/gymBookAction.do?ms=viewGymBook&gymnasium_id=2&item_id=5326&time_date=2019-02-21&userType=

Comment: @xinyueLiu you can check it by disabling javaScript inside your browser and loading the page. Or perhaps load the page source `view-source:<url>`

Answer (score 0):

What about waiting a while for page fully loaded.

```py
from splinter import Browser
b = Browser("chrome")
b.visit("https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html")

if b.is_element_present_by_xpath("//div[@id='create-a-browser-instance']/h2", wait_time=5):
    # wait until the element's appearing
    print(b.find_by_xpath("//div[@id='create-a-browser-instance']/h2"))
```

see more on [`splinter` documents](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drivers/chrome.html#splinter.driver.webdriver.chrome.WebDriver.is_element_present_by_xpath)

hope it helpful ..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know how to write `xpath` for the grid I want to select. But I think the following code is equal but failed.`if b.is_element_present_by_id('resourceTd_5897', wait_time = 5): print(b.find_by_id('resourceTd_5897'))`

Comment: @xinyueLiu, yeah, they are the same way, and your problem beyond my reach  for the url you provide is a local  area url....